# R - how to get values for specific row from file X to a proper row in file Y?

Tags: r

I have a serious issue with figuring the R function to solve the problem below:

I've used httr and rvest to **scrape** some data from couple of e-commerce sites and store them into different files as below:

**csv1** - columns: EAN, PRICE 
**csv2** - columns: EAN

ISSUE:
For each EAN from csv2, I want to search for the price value from csv1 and print it in column csv2$price for proper csv2$EAN.

Thanks in advance!
Bart

Comment: try ````dplyr```` package for data wrangling. Probably ````full_join```` function does what you expect.

Comment: Or `merge` in base R. See `?merge` for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

# import the data
csv1 <- read_csv("file path")
csv2 <- read_csv("file path")

# merge the data
result <- left_join(csv2, csv1, by = "EAN")
```

Comment: Welp... It was pretty simple! :D I used the "left_join" and works fine! Thanks, guys!